# How do I call a slice of a list in an if-statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I call a slice of a list in an `if` statement. I should check if the input is some of the members of the list on 1 and 2 index. It gives me `False`.

```
list1 = ["apple","kangaroo","elephant","cucumber"]
if userinput == list1[0:3]:
```

Comment: what is `userinput`?

Comment: check and see what `list1[0:3]` evaluates to (it's a list). you user input will be a string. I think you want to use the `in` operator

Comment: the input of an user I haven't written all the code with input before the list

Comment: I need to address words in the list on index 1 and 2 but it doesn't dress them when the input is True it is false

Comment: If you search in your browser for "Python find element in list", you'll find references that can explain this much better than we can manage here.

Comment: `if userInput in list1[1:3]:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct me if I misunderstand your question: you want the condition to evaluate to true when `userinput` matches any of the elements of `list1` at index 1 or 2.

If this is correct, and assuming `userinput` is a string, this should do the trick:

```
list1 = ["apple","kangaroo","elephant","cucumber"]
if userinput in list1[1:3]:
```

Answer (score 0):

The slice that contains elements `1` and `2` is `list1[1:3]`, not `list1[0:3]`.

Use the `in` operator to test if something matches any element of a list.

So what you want is:

```
if userinput in list1[1:3];
```